# .replace() variable string name

Tags: javascript

Will this effectively delete strings like: t_someString, o_someString, a_someString etc?
I don't know what the first character is going to be, `_someString` is the only known factor

`.replace( \*\ + '_someString', '' )`

Comment: huh? what's with the backslashes? not sure what you're doing...

Comment: You're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh? What's with the backslashes? And the asterisk? And the plus sign? Not sure what you're doing....

Anyway, here's a regex for that:

```
yourString = yourString.replace(/._someString/g, '')
```

`.` means "any character". The `g` flag is for global matching, so it replaces all occurences.

Comment: regarding the global occurrences... I know that the undetermined character will always be first and always a single character. Will using `g` possibly interfere with other parts of this string?

Comment: @user3024007 If by "interfere" you mean change "this_is_someString_and_it_is_a_string" to "this_i_and_it_is_a_string", then yes. You could use `\b` to fix that.